# Randomly pick a value from an array but always split it 50/50 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of hard coded names that won't change. There will also only be 2 values.

I need to loop through the array and pick a value at random but never to return the same value twice.

My current code is:

```
var pick_url = new Array('url_1', 'url_2');
var picked_url_to_use = pick_url[Math.floor(Math.random() * pick_url.length)];
var base_url = picked_url_to_use;

console.log(base_url);
```

This is working fine, but sometimes the same value is returned more than once.

Can anyone help resolve this please?

Comment: You could have a seperate array to hold the indexes of those already used?

Comment: It will be exactly two times, won't it?

Comment: You can also remove the items once you have picked them using array.splice();

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan how would i incorporate splice into this? My JS isn't that good.

Comment: @Rob How would I then check against that seperate array to determine to pick the last value that was picked?

Comment: @thomasbritton `var picked_url_to_use = pick_url.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pick_url.length), 1)[0];` would be the code to splice it.

Comment: @VisioN there will only ever be 2 values, just needs to always alternate between the 2 and never pick the same value one after the after so its 50% for value 1 and 50% for value 2

Comment: About splice: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp it goes like pick_url.splice(item_index, 1); Just save the whole Math.floor(...) in a previous item_index var so you can read the value in picked_url_to_use and you're done -- var item_index=Math.floor(Math.random() * pick_url.length); picked_url_to_use=pick_url[picked_index]; pick_url.splice(picked_index, 1); -- If I remember correctly the picked_url_to_use will copy the string value instead of refeencing it.

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan when i run this I am sometimes repeated outputs like, 1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1 etc

Comment: @TheMarlboroMan From the [MDN docs for `.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): "If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned." You'll need to access the first index of the return from `.splice()` in order to get the actual string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pick_url = ['url_1', 'url_2'];
var base_url = picked_url = pick_url.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pick_url.length), 1).join();
```

EDIT:  I'm not sure if you want to return always url_1 then url_2, or a random URL and then the other?

The following should return a random URL, and then the next URL on a subsequent call:

```
function rurl() { var picked_url = pick_url.splice(Math.max(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * pick_url.length)), 1).join(); return picked_url; }
```

If you wanted it to always return url_1 and then url_2, change Math.max to Math.min, or better still, just do pick_url.splice(0, 1).join();

Comment: thanks for this, but this still doesnt always give what I'm after. This gives rsponses like 1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2 etc where I need to get it so it would return this 1,2,1,2,1,2 etc

Comment: thanks for this, im not sure im applying this correctly, this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thomasbritton/A2QJm/ - could you check to see if this is right? As i'm still seeing it being reported like the others ie. 1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1 etc not 1,2,1,2,1

Comment: And if i do Math.min it only returns url_1

Comment: I am assuming you need to loop through the array once, is that correct, or do you wish to loop multiple times?

http://jsfiddle.net/quVVB/

Comment: It will need to multiple times as we are running this out to about 2000 recipients

Comment: Well, im not sure, the flow of how this should work is, check test is done, then check for special arguments then randomly pick either url_1 or url_2 then fire the ajax request with the chosen url from the pick_url array

Comment: Is the $loops neeeded for this?

Comment: No the for loop is just for testing.  Instantiate the object once, and call 'getUrl' as many times as nesecary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which values have been returned, there's two general options you can pick from:

You can delete the returned item from the `pick_url` array, so it can't be returned anymore.
For this, look into the `splice` function of javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

You could also just keep track of what already has been returned in a separate array. Then, when you get a second url, check if it has been sent before. If it has, pick a new random item, and re-check.
Theoretically, this could take ages if your random keeps picking already used items.

I'd opt for the first option, as it is faster and does not need to repeat itself.

Comment: Generally speaking people on SO don't consider W3Schools to be a good source, mostly because a lot of their information has a tendency to be outdated or plain incorrect. You may want to consider replacing the link to a more reputable source; I personally like the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript).

Comment: True, but `splice` is a pretty uneventful function, don't think it has changed much since its first implementation :) I know this page to be correct, a few months ago I was first introduced to `splice`, it works as mentioned on W3Schools.

Comment: The `howMany` parameter isn't required in IE9, and hasn't been required for quite some time in Firefox and Chrome, so there's at least one part where it's not entirely correct. The validity of the information on that particular page aside, it was more a general point that you probably want to avoid W3Schools in general when providing links to reference material here.

Answer (score 0):

If you really always have exactly two values in the array:

```
var pick_url = new Array('url_1', 'url_2');
var random_index1 = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2 );
var random_index2 = Math.abs( random_index1 - 1 );

console.log( pick_url[ random_index1 ] );  // either url_1 or url_2
console.log( pick_url[ random_index2 ] );  // always the other url
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jGurr/

Comment: I'd use `+!random_index1` or `random_index1^1` instead.

Comment: Yeah, or `random_index1 ? 0 : 1`... lots of options.

Comment: Not sure this would as I need to override a global variable called "base_url" with the next value in the array

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Perhaps if you would show the entire code. Why can't you just do `base_url = pick_url[ random_index2 ];` ?

Comment: @Juhana This is for an ajax request that fires off an html email and we want to do a split test on a generated html email so on success of the ajax call the url it sends will be the randomly picked url from the array which will be determined with some logic that is in place like so: $.ajax({url: base_url, success: ...}); etc

So how would I get random_index1 and random_index2 to somehow override the the 'base_url' variable value?

Comment: Ok. I still don't see what that has to do with the original question. So you want to get a random url from a list of two urls, but the problem is...?

Comment: @Juhana apologies, what I don't get in your solution is how would I get random_index1 and random_index2 actions to override the 'base_url' variables value with the new value

Comment: `base_url = pick_url[ random_index2 ];`

Comment: Or do you mean that the value should persist? So that the next time the page is loaded another URL is used? You do that with JavaScript only for one user using cookies or localstorage or whatnot. If you want to divide it equally for all users you need to set the value on the server.

Comment: I tried doing `base_url = pick_url[ random_index2 ];` but it doesnt always give the next value in the array, so it returns like 1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,2 etc

Comment: Yes, it works only on the same page. You need to save the previous value somewhere.

Comment: @Juhana this is what i am doing by using The Marlboro Mans solution up above to store the picked value into a new array with splice

Comment: That will only work for the current page. When you reload the page the script is reset and the value lost.